# Unable to get data from AJAX API using URL link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

(I just started learning JavaScript and AJAX)
in my project I need to get data from AJAX API using URL link.
button "Get All" plug-in directly and works without problems, but if I need to find something specific (use the search form) variable from 
not transmitted in URL.

and i don't get any error messages

Attachments area

```
   variable from <input type="text"/>
not transmitted in URL
----------

<button class="nav-link" id="getAllBtn">Get All</button>
<form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="currencyid" />
  <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
</form>


$("#getAllBtn").on("click", function() {
    console.log("home btn clicked")
    $.ajax({
        url: `http://www.example.com/`,
        method: "GET",
        success: function(result) {
            clearAll();
            $("#cryptoCards").html(getCurrenciesCard(result))
        },
        error: function() {
            clearAll();
            $("#cryptoCards").html("<h5>No Data!</h5>")
        }
    })
});

$("#searchBtn").on("click", function() {
    const currencyid = $("#currencyid").val();
    console.log("input: ", currencyid);
    $.ajax({
        url: `http://www.example.com/${currencyid}`,
        method: "GET",
        success: function(result) {
            clearAll();
            $("#cryptoCards").html(oneCurrencyCard(result))
        },
        error: function() {
            clearAll();
            $("#cryptoCards").html("<h5>No Data!</h5>")
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Have you debugged this at all? What is the value of `currencyid`? Is the URL format correct? What response do you see in the network tab of dev tools? Any errors in the console?

Comment: value of currencyid* - is what I type in <input/> field.

Comment: when you say you get no errors, do you mean in the browser **developer** tools console? You have checked the developer tools, right? With not much information about the end point of the request, the only thing that comes to mind is CORS

Comment: URL format correc(I checked)! , no Arrors! but I have strange response:

Comment: log your response in console and post here

Comment: Navigated to file:///C:/Users/...../test/index.html?

Comment: OK, the button is in a form, clicking on it will submit the form - I suggest you don't use a form - or `<button type="button" ....` that will prevent the button from submitting the form

Comment: e.preventDefault();  !!!! 
it is working!!! thanks to all :)))

Answer (score 0):

A `<button>`'s type defaults to `submit` - therefore you are submitting the form so none of your `click` action will run

simplest solution is to make the button NOT submit the form

```
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="currencyid" />
  <button type="button" class="btn my-2 my-sm-0" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
</form>
```

or another solution is to prevent the default behaviour

```
$("#searchBtn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const currencyid = $("#currencyid").val();
```

Comment: e.preventDefault();   --was missing

Comment: or `button type="button"` - that would be how I'd do it, but each to their own

Answer (score 0):

you havent set data on ajax api. so ajax cant recognize your data. also, your request url is : http://www.example.com/${currencyid} , so your request would be:  http://www.example.com/5 , and your server search this as url, function/method something else. Here is some ways to use get method:

- set url like this: http://www.example.com?id=${currencyid}
- set data in ajax api like this: data:{'id':currencyid}

one of these ways should work.